# Finding a mod m where a mod 2^i are known

Tags: math, complexity-theory, performance, modulus, modular-arithmetic

I need to find the value of `a mod m`.
But I dont have the value of `a` directly. I have the following modulus values of `a`.
a mod 2<sup>1</sup>
a mod 2<sup>2</sup>
a mod 2<sup>3</sup>
...
a mod 2<sup>n</sup>

Now I need to find `a mod m` where `m < 2`<sup>`n`</sup>
Can this be done in O(n) time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done at all without more information, let alone in O(n) time.

Note first that you only have one piece of information: namely, the value of `a mod 2^n`; all of the earlier remainders can be computed from `a mod 2^n` by reduction, so they don't provide new information.

And then if, for example, `m` is odd, the value of `a mod 2^n` tells you exactly nothing about the value of `a mod m`: the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) tells you that for *any* values `0 <= b < 2^n` and `0 <= c < m`, you can find a value of `a` such that `a mod 2^n = b` and `a mod m = c`.

If `m` is even but not a power of `2` then you get partial information about the possibilities for `a mod m`.  Only in the case that `m` is a power of `2` less than or equal to `2^n` can you determine (trivially, by reduction) the value of `a mod m`.

Comment: Another way to think about it: Consider the case where you know that `a mod 4 = 3` then clearly `a mod 2 = 1`. I think once you know `a mod 2^n`, the rest of the list of remainders provides redundant information. Then it's fairly obvious you cannot compute `a mod m`.